# RIA.Net Authentication/Complex Custom Profile Settings

Tags: c#, authentication, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a database that have quite a bit relational user information that would be handy to load when the user is authenticated. I would like to use the Silverlight Business Application project template and extend the user class that exists in the AuthebticationService.cs file in that project.

I have been able to add simple properties to the User class, such as those with a type of string. When I add a more complex type as a property, such as my own custom objects, the code compiles fine, but the properties do not show up in the silverlight client app project.

What is the best way to get them over? Set up another domain service?

Thanls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way of adding complex properties to the User class. Creating a new domain service was easy enough.